# Getting old intent extras in onResume() after startActivity(newIntent)

Tags: android

In the calling activity, I have the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(CallingActivity.this, CalledActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(key, new_value);
startActivity(intent);
```

After the    startActivity(intent) is called, the control goes to onResume() of the CalledActivity.

However, in the onResume() of the CalledActivity, getIntent() gives me the old intent and not the new intent as set by the CallingActivity.

How can I get the new intent in onResume() of the CalledActivity??

Comment: Have you marked activity as `single task` or `single top`

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 12):

You should try to override the `onNewIntent (Intent intent)` method of Activity, and use `setIntent(Intent)` to update the intent.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on dreamtale's answer, just add the following method to your Activity.

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
}
```