# How to determine what kind of onResume has happened

Tags: android, push-notification

I need to create a new object when a user comes from the `push notification`.

When user clicks on the notification, `onResume` is triggered (on purpose). In the `onResume` method, I need to make a call to the server and create an object, based on response. However, I can't figure out how to determine, whether the `onResume` was triggered by the notification or by something else, like turning on the screen.

I don't understand much about `Intent flags`, but maybe solution could lie there.

This is the code which configures and triggers the `push notification`:

```
private void sendNotification(String message, String topic) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("resumeType", "BattleNotification");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String contentTitle = "Message from Maguss";
    switch (topic){
        case "battle":
            contentTitle = "Your battle was accepted";
            break;
    }
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers were good, however they didn't work. I still had to add this:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

As explained here: [Getting old intent extras in onResume() after startActivity(newIntent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925963/getting-old-intent-extras-in-onresume-after-startactivitynewintent)

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you can get the intent that has started it, and then inspect it to find out if it was from notification or not. Probably something along the lines of

`if (getIntent().getStringExtra("resumeType") != null) { /* from notification */ }`

would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onResume` method you can check if you came from push notification or from another activity. See following code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String resumeType = getIntent().getStringExtra("resumeType");
    if (resumeType!=null && resumeType.equalsIgnoreCase("BattleNotification")){
            // from push notification
    }else{

    }
}
```